# Reading multiple XML attributes

Tags: c#, xml

I'm trying to get information from XML library (file below) using C# in Visual Studio.

```
<buttons>
<measurement>
    <scan id="0" time="20 53 06">
        <q address="40" state="0"/>
        <q address="41" state="0"/>
        <q address="42" state="1"/>
        <q address="43" state="0"/>
        <q address="44" state="1"/>
        <q address="45" state="1"/>
        <q address="46" state="1"/>
        <q address="47" state="1"/>
    </scan>
</measurement>
<measurement>
    <scan id="1" time="20 53 07">
        <q address="40" state="0"/>
        <q address="41" state="0"/>
        <q address="42" state="0"/>
        <q address="43" state="0"/>
        <q address="44" state="1"/>
        <q address="45" state="0"/>
        <q address="46" state="0"/>
        <q address="47" state="0"/>
    </scan>
</measurement>
<measurement>
    <scan id="2" time="20 53 08">
        <q address="40" state="0"/>
        <q address="41" state="1"/>
        <q address="42" state="0"/>
        <q address="43" state="1"/>
        <q address="44" state="1"/>
        <q address="45" state="0"/>
        <q address="46" state="0"/>
        <q address="47" state="1"/>
    </scan>
</measurement>
<measurement>
    <scan id="3" time="20 53 09">
        <q address="40" state="1"/>
        <q address="41" state="0"/>
        <q address="42" state="0"/>
        <q address="43" state="1"/>
        <q address="44" state="1"/>
        <q address="45" state="0"/>
        <q address="46" state="1"/>
        <q address="47" state="0"/>
    </scan>
</measurement>
<measurement>
    <scan id="4" time="20 53 10">
        <q address="40" state="0"/>
        <q address="41" state="0"/>
        <q address="42" state="1"/>
        <q address="43" state="1"/>
        <q address="44" state="1"/>
        <q address="45" state="1"/>
        <q address="46" state="0"/>
        <q address="47" state="0"/>
    </scan>
</measurement>
<measurement>
    <scan id="5" time="20 53 11">
        <q address="40" state="1"/>
        <q address="41" state="1"/>
        <q address="42" state="1"/>
        <q address="43" state="0"/>
        <q address="44" state="0"/>
        <q address="45" state="0"/>
        <q address="46" state="1"/>
        <q address="47" state="0"/>
    </scan>
</measurement>
<measurement>
    <scan id="6" time="20 53 12">
        <q address="40" state="0"/>
        <q address="41" state="1"/>
        <q address="42" state="1"/>
        <q address="43" state="0"/>
        <q address="44" state="0"/>
        <q address="45" state="1"/>
        <q address="46" state="1"/>
        <q address="47" state="1"/>
    </scan>
</measurement>
<measurement>
    <scan id="7" time="20 53 13">
        <q address="40" state="1"/>
        <q address="41" state="1"/>
        <q address="42" state="1"/>
        <q address="43" state="1"/>
        <q address="44" state="1"/>
        <q address="45" state="0"/>
        <q address="46" state="1"/>
        <q address="47" state="1"/>
    </scan>
</measurement>
```

it is my first attempt to do and read xml files.

Hre is what i want to do:
I want to inpud ID and program schould return all q states in array.

Here is what I tried:

```
using System.Xml;
XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
xmlDoc.Load("Path to my xml");
XmlNodeList titleNodes = xmlDoc.SelectNodes("//buttons/measurment/scan/q");
foreach(XmlNode titleNode in titleNodes)
    Console.WriteLine(titleNode.Attribute["address"]);
Console.ReadKey();
```

I know that this code will only display some q atributes in console. I never went furder because it is not working (nothing appears in console window) . And i dont know why. I just don understand this XmlRead, XmlDeocument. I was learnig form here: [Tutorial](http://csharp.net-tutorials.com/xml/introduction/). I was folowing every stem and examlpes. Only XmlRead giave something to me. Bu it reads just everything, not specific regions.

Can you show me some examples or solutions?

Comment: I'm not looking into this too much, but your `SelectNodes` has the wrong casing - Try changing the upper case "Q" - `"//buttons/measurment/scan/q"`

Comment: you input the scan id, and get all the q states? is that what you're asking

Comment: My mistake during prescribing

Comment: All q states from specific scan area. For examle tag scan has atribute id="0" and i wan all q states from this tag area.

Comment: What you want to do is something like this: SelectNodes("//scan[contains(id,""'YOURSELECTEDID'"")]")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the xml is well formed and the root node is corectly closed,
you have a typo in the string `measurement` and this is correctly selecting all the `q` tags

```
XmlNodeList titleNodes = xmlDoc.SelectNodes("//buttons/measurement/scan/q");
```

If you want only the ones under one id

```
XmlNodeList titleNodes = xmlDoc.SelectNodes("//buttons/measurement/scan[@id=2]/q") ;
```

If there is no such id, you'll get an empty collection but not an exception error: so that case is managed.

Finally, don't forget the `Value` field

```
Console.WriteLine(titleNode.Attributes["address"].Value);
```

Comment: Your solution looks the best, but (i don't know why) Attributes are not recognised. I just get red line under this word. And sorry for typos. I'm not a native english speaker,I translated my code so it is more redable here.

Comment: After some tweaking everything works( my part of the code, your is perfect :) ). Thanks, you helped me alot :)

Answer (score 3):

Consider using `XDocument`, which allows you to use LINQ, making your xml life easier:

```
string myId = "2";

var doc = XDocument.Parse(xmlString); //or XDocument.Load(filePath)

//find the correct 'scan' node based on your id
var scan = doc.Descendants("scan")
              .FirstOrDefault(s => s.Attribute("id").Value == myId);

//grab all q's and get their 'state' for that 'scan' node
var states = scan?.Descendants("q")
                  .Select(q => q.Attribute("state").Value);

foreach (var state in states)
{
    Console.WriteLine(state);
}
```

Comment: If the scan is null (when the id is not found), you'll get a `NullReferenceException` in the foreach... so `?.` only puts it off to the next instruction

Comment: I'd suggest a `var states = scan?.Descendants("q").Select(q => q.Attribute("state").Value) ?? Enumerable.Empty <string>();`  :-) but of course there are thousand ways...

Comment: This solution looks good, but VisualStudio don't recodnise XDocument. And yes I added System.Linq library.

Comment: @MrJW the namespace for [XDocument](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument(v=vs.110).aspx) is [System.Xml.Linq](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq(v=vs.110).aspx) and minimum .Net Framework is 3.5 (Visual Studio 2008)

Comment: I typed file path, for example "XDocument.Parse(/data/test.xml)" file test.xml containt data described in my main post. I also added library System.Xml.Linq but when I run application, excepion unhandle apperars:
"An unhandled exception of type 'System.Xml.XmlException' occurred in System.Xml.dll

Additional information: Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1. "

Comment: your xml doesnt have a closng `buttons` tag

Answer (score 0):

```
XmlNodeList titleNodes = xmlDoc.SelectNodes("//measurement/scan/q");
```

Then you will get 64 items back.